# add < and > sign in ng-repeat and filter accordingly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data on bikes on HTMl page, Which have some filter on page like 'brand', 'year' and price. although brand and year filter is working fine but I have some issue with price filter.

So I have to less then and greater then sign conditionally. 
I have to show < then sign with the price 50000 and > with the price 500000. And apply filter accordingly

http://jsfiddle.net/zL4x971f/

```
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-class="{sel: $index == selected}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filter.name}}

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="filterValue in filter.lists">
                  <input ng-checked="activeFilters.brand[filterValue] !== undefined" ng-click="toggleFilter(filter.name, filterValue)" type="checkbox">  {{filterValue}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as listCtrl">
        <div class="list" ng-repeat="list in lists | filter: activeFilters">
            {{list.brand}},
            {{list.year}} ,
            {{list.price}}
        </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.activeFilters = {

        };

        $scope.filters = [
                {
                    name: "brand",
                    lists: ['yamaha','ducati','KTM','honda']
                },
                {
                    name: "year",
                    lists: [2012,2014,2015]
                },{
                name:"price",
                lists:[50000,100000,20000,500000]
                }
            ];

        $scope.toggleFilter= function(filterName, filterValue) {

            if ($scope.activeFilters[filterName] === undefined) {

                $scope.activeFilters[filterName] = filterValue;
            } else {

                delete $scope.activeFilters[filterName];
            }
        };

    });


    app.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.lists = [
                {
                    "brand": "ducati",
                    'year': 2012,
                    'price':40000
                },
                {
                    'brand': "honda",
                    'year': 2014,
                    'price':50000
                },
                {
                    'brand': "yamaha",
                    'year': 2015,
                    'price':200000
                },
                {
                    'brand': "KTM",
                    'year': 2012,
                    'price':500000
                },
                 {
                    'brand': "KTM",
                    'year': 2015,
                    'price':800000
                }

            ];

    });
```

Comment: if i understood your question correctly.. do you want to have 2 additional filter as <50000 and >500000 on price??

Comment: @Hrishi: yes, If I choose < 50000 then price having price 50000 or below 50000 should display

Comment: You may have to write custom filter for that since angular default filter are doing the text comparison..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is to write a custom filter. Also, remember to update the price checkboxes so that the user can choose only one at a time. You can have a look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/so9x7qpy/

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.activeFilters = {};
       
    $scope.filters = [
        {
            name: "brand",
            lists: ['yamaha','ducati','KTM','honda']
        },
        {
            name: "year",
            lists: [2012,2014,2015]
        },
        {
            name:"price",
            lists:['< 50000', '50000','100000','200000','500000', '> 500000']
        }
    ];

    $scope.toggleFilter= function(filterName, filterValue) {       
        if (!$scope.activeFilters[filterName]) {                  
            $scope.activeFilters[filterName] = [];
            return $scope.activeFilters[filterName].push(filterValue);  
        }
          
        var curFilter = $scope.activeFilters[filterName];
        var i = curFilter.indexOf(filterValue);
        if (i === -1) {
            curFilter.push(filterValue);
        } else {
            curFilter.splice(i, 1);
        }
        
        if (filterName === 'price' && curFilter.length > 1) {
         curFilter.shift();        
        }
    };
})
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.lists = [
        {
            "brand": "ducati",
            'year': 2012,
            'price':40000
        },
        {
            'brand': "honda",
            'year': 2014,
            'price':50000
        },
        {
            'brand': "yamaha",
            'year': 2015,
            'price':200000
        },
        {
            'brand': "KTM",
            'year': 2012,
            'price':500000
        },
        {
            'brand': "KTM",
            'year': 2015,
            'price':800000
        }

    ];
})
.filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(data, filter) {
        var list = [];
        
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         var item = data[i];
            
            if (filter.brand && 
                filter.brand.length > 0 && 
                filter.brand.indexOf(item.brand) === -1) 
                continue;
            
            if (filter.year &&
                filter.year.length > 0 && 
                filter.year.indexOf(item.year) === -1) 
                continue;
            
            if (filter.price && filter.price.length > 0) {
                var re = /<|>/;
                if (re.test(filter.price)) {
                    if (eval(item.price + filter.price)) {
                        list.push(item);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (eval(item.price == filter.price)) {
                        list.push(item);
                    }
                }
            } else {
             list.push(item);
            }
        }
                
        return list;
    }
});
```

```css
.sel {
    color:red
}
.nav > li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding-right:20px
}
.subul {
    display:none
}
.sel ul {
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0
}
.list {
    padding-top:30px;
    clear:both
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-class="{sel: $index == selected}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filter.name}}
            
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="filterValue in filter.lists">
                  <input ng-checked="activeFilters[filter.name] && activeFilters[filter.name].indexOf(filterValue) !== -1" ng-click="toggleFilter(filter.name, filterValue)" type="checkbox">  {{filterValue}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as listCtrl">
        <div class="list" ng-repeat="list in lists | myFilter: activeFilters">
            {{list.brand}},
            {{list.year}} ,
            {{list.price}}
        </div>
            
        </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier.. please see below the working JSFiddle with customer Filters
and as mentioned

`woking JSFiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/hrishi1183/zL4x971f/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search strictly on value you can use

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="list in lists | filter: activeFilters:true">

            {{list.brand}},
            {{list.year}} ,
            {{list.price}}
        </div>
```

But if you are planning for some **custom filter** May be this link can help you

[AngularJS filtering between a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728666/angularjs-filtering-between-a-range)