# Only display items below £10 with Angular Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a list of products generated from a third party JSON feed, the prices will vary depending on the current price from the 3rd party.

How can I only display prices on the page below for a certain value, such as below £10.00?

I assume AngularJS filters will come into play here but now sure how it works with an expression such as item.products_price, but even better if a slider or something is also possible. So products are displayed below based on the value range in a slider.

Here is my 'List' code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <script>
            document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <ion-content class="has-subheader">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in products | filter:query" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
                <img ng-src="img/{{item.products_image}}" alt="{{item.products_name}} Photo">
                <h2>{{item.products_name}}</h2>
                <h3>{{item.products_model}}</h3>
                <p>{{item.products_price}}</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

    </html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lV5GUPkU9EWUiedHuA1l

Comment: An angular filter is code used to format an object as text. Example: there are date filters which can format a date object in various ways so they show in a specific way on the screen. It has nothing to do with filtering out values. You should build a method into your angular Controller that retrieves a subset of your array based on some input like amount. You can then call this in your `ng-repeat` attribute. Example: `ng-repeat="item in getProductsBelow(10)"` and create a function with the same name that returns those products that are below the input.

Comment: I think the answer to this question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728666/angularjs-filtering-between-a-range

Comment: @Igor That's not entirely true. You can create a custom `.filter()` in Angular that takes inputs to perform filtering on a list returning an array containing only those items that meet your filter criteria. This is more advantageous than writing a controller method because you can reuse this filter throughout your app without having to write the code in a bunch of different controllers.

Comment: @Lex, thanks thats good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is write a custom filter. Here is one way you might structure the filter:

```
.filter('valueRange', function() {
    return function(productList, minValue, maxValue) {
        // make sure something was passed - you can decide if you want to use defaults
        if(!productList || !minValue || !maxValue) {
            return productList;
        }

        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(productList, function(product) {
            if(product.products_price >= minValue && product.products_price <= maxValue) {
                out.push(product);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});
```

Then you can use it in your `ng-repeat` as:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in products | valueRange:minValue:maxValue" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
```

This part - `valueRange:minValue:maxValue` - will call the `valueRange` filter, pass in `products` as the first parameter, `minValue` as the second parameter and `maxValue` as the third parameter. You can get these values from your slider.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try

```
ng-if="item.products_price<10"
```

or

```
ng-show="item.products_price<10"
```