# filter data using range slider angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to populate result using range slider. when user changing price, result set should change accordingly.  please check attached image.[Result View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD3LI.jpg)

```
var mainlist = 
[
    {company: 'ABC', vtype: 'car', price:'5000'},
        {company: 'DCC', vtype: 'Van', price:'1000'},
        {company: 'ABC', vtype: 'car', price:'3000'}  
];
```

Comment: where is your code what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS filtering between a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728666/angularjs-filtering-between-a-range)

Comment: that image looks like you're on the right path - when you have an issue, ask again after searching for a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23729095/5053002) for the same issue first, of course

Comment: Thank you manish. i am working with your solution (link).

Comment: Perfectly worked !! Thanks again